# Varchar column from SQL Server shows as "???" on classic ASP webpage hosted on Azure

Tags: character-encoding, asp-classic, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to move some old classic ASP website to Azure App Service. The webpages work fine, but show national characters from `varchar` columns as question marks.

How to reproduce:

- Create a SQL Server database (on Azure or on other SQL Server) with `Cyrillic_General_100_CI_AS collation`
- Create the table with `varchar` and `nvarchar` columns:

  ```
  create table dbo.Test 
  (
        id int identity (1,1) not null,
        code varchar(255) null,
        name nvarchar(255) null
  )
  ```
- Insert some test data:

  ```
  insert dbo.Test (code, name) 
  values ('привет-1', N'привет-2')

  insert dbo.Test (code, name) 
  values ('привет-3', N'привет-4')
  ```
- Ensure that data is selected fine in SSMS:

  ```
  select * from dbo.Test:

  id  code    name
  1   привет-1    привет-2
  2   привет-3    привет-4
  ```
- Create a webpage that displays data:

  ```
  id  code    name
  1   ??????-1    привет-2
  2   ??????-3    привет-4
  ```

So, the `nvarchar` columns show up fine, but `varchar` columns do not. Using the following code on the Azure web page doesn't help:

```
Response.CharSet = "windows-1251"
Response.CodePage = 1251
Session.CodePage = 1251
```

On "regular" IIS everything is shown fine - maybe because it has "ASP encoding" setting. Anybody knows how to fix that on Azure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, then use `nvarchar` for anything Cyrillic and be done with it ! Cyrillic characters do need the Unicode support that only the `nvarchar` datatype can provide. So what exactly is the question then?? Just use `nvarchar`:...

Comment: Marc, on "regular" IIS the same webpage worked fine for years and works fine now, even with varchar. Why it cannot work on Azure? And converting the existing varchar columns to nvarchar on existing (big!) database is not an option - because it requires also mass changes to existing webpages (adding N' to every insert statement etc..)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to change varchar to nvarchar as marc_s said. If it is not a good solution for you, please try to set Collation as "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" when creating your Azure SQL Database. Refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508(v=sql.105).aspx) for more detailed information.

[image]

Here is my result: (just create a mvc controller with view using Entity framework)

[image]

Comment: Hi Jambor. Thank you, I have no issues with ASP.NET applications - they are showing national characters fine. The issue exists in Classic ASP webpages, and only on Azure. On "regular" IIS the same classic ASP pages work fine.

Comment: As I know, Azure Web App does not support install language package. If you need this function, please vote [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9854277-provide-net-language-packs-on-web-apps). At currently, I am afraid you need to change your source code. If possible you could replace your column name like this `select 'N'+CAST(o.code AS NVARCHAR(4000)) from dbo.Test o`. The best solution is changing varchar to nvarchar in SQL Azure.